# Error in XML file that I cannot pinpoint

Tags: android, xml

I am currently getting errors about my `xml` files, `styles.xml` and `row.xml` (a file in `layout/`. Here is the `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"> </style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"> </style>

<style name="AudioFileInfoOverlayText">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">4px</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">4px</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
</style>

<style name="Divider">
    <item name="android:layout_width">1dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">#0F6F6F6F</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">#6ABD7B</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

The error in the console says that the problem is on the last line:

```
 error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag   styles.xml  /Tabcards/res/values    line 46 Android AAPT Problem
```

The next problem is directly linked to this (the style `Divider` in the `styles.xml` file) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rowRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rowImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <View style="@style/Divider" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Textview
        android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

</TableRow>
```

and the error:

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '@style/Divider').   row.xml /Tabcards/res/layout    line 23 Android AAPT Problem
```

I have tried everything but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't save the `styles.xml` and try to reference a new added style in your layout xml, like `row.xml`, the IDE won't see the added style. So it will point error.

I had the same issue with Eclipse many times!

**So what I do:** modify the `styles.xml` or `dimen.xml`, save it and reference on layout.xml

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem... But it was very weird. I deleted the `Divider` style inside the `styles.xml` folder, and the problem was gone. I put it back in and now it works... I really want a better IDE for android.